# Swift exchange variables between View and its ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController:

```
class graphicViewController: UIViewController {
    var pathToFile = "" //it's changed in method PrepareForSegue from previous ViewController
}
```

and I have a View:

```
class graphicView: UIView {
   var ltr:String?
   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
      println(ltr!)
   }
}
```

How and where should I implement access/transfer of variable pathToFile that it must not be null in drawRect?

Comment: Is `graphicView` the type view in your `graphicViewController `?

Comment: @Mike, `graphicView` is the subview of `graphicViewController`. I can access graphicView like this: `graphicViewController.view as graphicView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting your `pathToFile` property in `prepareForSegue`, the best place to pass the value of the property on would be would be in `graphicViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let gView = view as? graphicView {
        gView.ltr = pathToFile
    }
}
```

***Sidenote:** Typically you'll want to name your types with a capital letter and your instances with a lower case letter. So, `graphicView` would be `GraphicView`, etc.*